# Combine multiple rows based on one colum value and add extra columns based on other column value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
     Name   rollNumber   external_roll_number    testDate      marks 

0    John      34             234               2021-04-28      15 

1    John      34             234               2021-03-28      25
```

I would like to convert it like this:

```
     Name   rollNumber   external_roll_number    testMonth      marks    testMonth      marks

0    John      34             234                  April          15       March         25
```

If the above is not possible then I would atleast want it to be like this:

```
     Name   rollNumber   external_roll_number    testDate      marks    testDate      marks

0    John      34             234                2021-04-28      15     2021-03-28       25
```

How can I convert my dataframe to the desired output? This change will be based on the `Name` column of the rows.

**EDIT 1**

I tried using `pivot_table` like this but I did not get the desired result.

```
merged_df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(merged_df, index=["name", "testDate"], aggfunc="first", dropna=False).fillna("")
```

When I try to iterate through the `merged_df_pivot` like this:

```
for index, details in merged_df_pivot.iterrows():
```

I am again getting two rows and also I was not able to add the new `testMonth` column by the above method.

Comment: I have added the code that I had tried before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- core is `unstack()` month to be columns
- detail then to re-structure month-by month **marks** columns to required structure
- generally consider bad practice to have duplicate column names,  hence have suffixed them

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""     Name   rollNumber   external_roll_number    testDate      marks 
0    John      34             234               2021-04-28      15 
1    John      34             234               2021-03-28      25
"""), sep="\s+")

df["testDate"] =pd.to_datetime(df["testDate"])
df = df.assign(testMonth = df["testDate"].dt.strftime("%B")).drop(columns="testDate")


dft = (df.set_index([c for c in df.columns if c!="marks"])
 .unstack("testMonth") # make month a column
 .droplevel(0, axis=1) # remove unneeded level in columns
 # create columns for months from column names and rename marks columns
 .pipe(lambda d: d.assign(**{f"testMonth_{i+1}":c 
                             for i,c in enumerate(d.columns)}).rename(columns={c:f"marks_{i+1}" 
                                                                               for i,c in enumerate(d.columns)}))
 .reset_index()
)
```

#### output

|  | Name | rollNumber | external_roll_number | marks_1 | marks_2 | testMonth_1 | testMonth_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John | 34 | 234 | 15 | 25 | April | March |

Comment: Is there anyway to send all column names at once in `set_index` instead of specifying each one explicitly? I have added only some columns for the purpose of this question. There are more than 20 columns in the dataframe in reality.

Comment: yep - updated.  use a list comprehension excluding col that should not go into index

Comment: on actual data or the sample data in the question?  if actual data I'll need the to see actual columns and a few rows to check reason

Comment: Hey. Thanks. I resolved it. It was my mistake.